# Oracle SQL String Compare

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

I have the following entries in the table:

```
SQL> select TO_CHAR(startdate, 'DAY') from ragreement;

TO_CHAR(STARTDATE,'DAY')
------------------------------------
WEDNESDAY
THURSDAY
SUNDAY
FRIDAY
MONDAY
SUNDAY
MONDAY
MONDAY
THURSDAY
SATURDAY
TUESDAY
SUNDAY
FRIDAY
WEDNESDAY
FRIDAY
SUNDAY
THURSDAY
MONDAY
THURSDAY
WEDNESDAY
TUESDAY
TUESDAY
MONDAY
SUNDAY
WEDNESDAY
FRIDAY
SUNDAY
MONDAY
WEDNESDAY

29 rows selected.
```

I would like to count the dates that are 'Mondays', 'Tuesdays' and so on...
However, I get the following:

```
SQL> select count(*) from ragreement where UPPER(TO_CHAR(startdate, 'DAY')) = 'TUESDAY';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL> select count(*) from ragreement where UPPER(TO_CHAR(startdate, 'DAY')) = 'MONDAY';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM ragreement
  WHERE TRIM(TO_CHAR(startdate, 'DAY')) = 'TUESDAY'
```

I think there is space padding space padding.  Don't need `UPPER` since the formatting model used already is forcing upper case.

Please see [Number Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216)

> The character elements MONTH, MON, DAY, and DY are padded with
>   trailing blanks to the width of the longest full month name, the
>   longest abbreviated month name, the longest full date name, or the
>   longest abbreviated day name, respectively, among valid names
>   determined by the values of NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE and NLS_CALENDAR
>   parameters.

Comment: good answer, please add a link of the doc where you found the information.

Answer (score 0):

Glenn is right - the problem is by default Oracle pads the `DAY` format mask with spaces up to 9 characters I believe. Just to add to Glenn's suggestion (which is good) you can also use

`TO_CHAR(startdate, 'fmDAY'))`

to remove the trailing spaces. Or you could use

`TO_CHAR(startdate,'D') = 2`

(I think 2 is Tuesday, 1=Mon, 2=TUE, ... 7=SUN), which is better from a localisation point of view.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, here is an alternative:

```
SELECT t.day, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT TRIM(TO_CHAR(startdate, 'DAY')) day FROM ragreement) t
GROUP BY
    t.day
```

Naturally since no string comparison is involved in this solution, this could (and should) be simplified:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(startdate, 'DAY'), COUNT(*)
FROM ragreement
GROUP BY
    TO_CHAR(startdate, 'DAY')
```